# How to set a database integrity check on foreign keys referenced fields

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, constraints

I have four Database Tables like these:

> **Book**
>   ID_Book |ID_Company|Description
>
> **BookExtension**
>   ID_BookExtension | ID_Book| ID_Discount
>
> **Discount**
>   ID_Discount | Description | ID_Company
>
> **Company**
>   ID_Company | Description

Any `BookExtension` record via foreign keys points indirectly to two different `ID_Company` fields:

> BookExtension.ID_Book references a Book record that contains a Book.ID_Company
>   BookExtension.ID_Discount references a Discount record that contains a Discount.ID_Company

Is it possible to enforce in Sql Server that any new record in `BookExtension` must have `Book.ID_Company = Discount.ID_Company` ?

In a nutshell I want that the following Query must return 0 record!

```
SELECT count(*) from BookExtension 
INNER JOIN Book ON BookExstension.ID_Book = Book.ID_Book
INNER JOIN Discount ON BookExstension.ID_Discount = Discount.ID_Discount
WHERE Book.ID_Company <> Discount.ID_Company
```

or, in plain English:
I don't want that a `BookExtension` record references a `Book` record of a `Company` and a `Discount` record of another different `Company`!

Comment: You say "any new record" - Does this constraint also apply to already existing records?

Comment: @Martin The existing records are good because, once the new ID_Discount field was added to BookExtension, all the records and the respective ID_Discount values were bulk updated following a strict rule. This table is now fed by a web application and although I can double check from the app before inserting a new record, I would like to enforce this constraint using a db rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood your intent, the general form of the SQL statement you'd use is

```
ALTER TABLE FooExtension
ADD CONSTRAINT your-constraint-name
CHECK (ID_Foo = ID_Bar);
```

That assumes existing data already conforms to the new constraint. If existing data doesn't conform, you can either fix the data (assuming it needs fixing), or you can limit the scope (probably) of the new constraint by also checking the value of ID_FooExtension. (Assuming you can identify "new" rows by the value of ID_FooExtension.)

**Later . . .**

Thanks, I did indeed misunderstand your situation.

As far as I know, you can't enforce that constraint the way you want to in SQL Server, because it doesn't allow SELECT queries within a CHECK constraint. (I might be wrong about that in SQL Server 2008.) A common workaround is to wrap a SELECT query in a function, and call the function, but that's not reliable according to what I've learned.

You *can* do this, though.

1. Create a UNIQUE constraint on Book
   (ID_Book, ID_Company). Part of it will look like `UNIQUE (ID_Book, ID_Company)`.
2. Create a UNIQUE constraint on Discount (ID_Discount, ID_Company).
3. Add two columns to
   BookExtension--Book_ID_Company and
   Discount_ID_Company.
4. Populate those new columns.
5. Change the foreign key constraints
   in    BookExtension. You want
   BookExtension    (ID_Book,
   Book_ID_Company) to    reference
   Book (ID_Book, ID_Company). Similar change for the foreign key
   referencing Discount.

*Now* you can add a check constraint to guarantee that BookExtension.Book_ID_Company is the same as BookExtension.Discount_ID_Company.

Comment: Are you under the impression that changing the string "Foo" to "Book" and the string "Bar" to "Discount" creates a completely different problem? It doesn't.

Comment: @Cat is `ID_Foo = ID_Bar` a generic example (foo,bar) on how to create a constraint or is it specific to my problem? I changed the tables name to understand it.

Comment: It's generic in the sense that all CHECK constraints are created the same way, by `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT constraintname` etc. You can look it up in your "help" system. It's specific to your problem in that the table name you gave was "FooExtension", and the column names that needed to be compared were "ID_Foo" and "ID_Bar". I'm sure you can convert those names to your actual table and column names yourself.

Comment: @Cat the constraint you are suggesting can't work, `ID_Book = ID_Discount` on BookExtension is wrong. What I need is that ID_Company on Book table is equal to ID_Company on Discount table starting from a BookExtension record that points to Book and Discount respectively. Anyway the fault is mine since my question is not clear enough.

Comment: You said you have a foreign key constraint from BookExtension.ID_Book to Book.ID_Company. That means that only a value that exists in Book.ID_Company can exist in BookExtension.ID_Book. So values in the column ID_Book represent companies, and ID_Book is equivalent to ID_Company. Personally, I don't think that makes sense, but I trust you to know what you have.

Comment: @Cat see my edit. You probably misunderstood my situation. Anyway +1 for the support :).

Comment: @Cat that's an interesting approach, thanks and sorry for my uglier than ugly question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how [in]efficient this would be but you could also use an indexed view to achieve this. It needs a helper table with 2 rows as CTEs and `UNION` are not allowed in indexed views.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TwoNums
 (
 Num int primary key
 )

 INSERT INTO TwoNums SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2
```

Then the view definition

```
 CREATE VIEW dbo.ConstraintView
 WITH SCHEMABINDING
 AS
    SELECT 1 AS Col FROM dbo.BookExtension 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Book ON dbo.BookExtension.ID_Book = Book.ID_Book
    INNER JOIN dbo.Discount ON dbo.BookExtension.ID_Discount = Discount.ID_Discount
    INNER JOIN dbo.TwoNums ON  Num = Num
    WHERE dbo.Book.ID_Company <> dbo.Discount.ID_Company
```

And a unique index on the View

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [uix] ON [dbo].[ConstraintView]([Col] ASC)
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN dbo.TwoNums ON  Num = Num` is effectively `CROSS JOIN dbo.TwoNums`. Are cross joins forbidden (syntactically) in indexed views as well?

Comment: @Andriy M - I was too lazy to check at the time! No `OUTER JOIN` and self joins are but `CROSS JOIN` *is* permitted.